# NPM ERR! Test failed - Not able to run test

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

Running a few tests for react js using Jest and Enzyme but one of the files keeps breaking. Using Jest and Enzyme

I already cleared the cache, but I keep getting the following :

> ```
> NPM ERR ! Test failed
> and worker process has quit unexpectedly!
> ```

Most likely this is an initialization error
Here is part of the package.json.
Not really sure how to fix this problem.

```
scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "start-3001": "set PORT=3001&& node scripts/start.js",
    "start-3002": "set PORT=3002&& node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom --verbose || exit 0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "jes": "^0.6.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^2.1.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
     "automock": false, 
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost:3000",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add code snippets and config files.  Nobody is going to be able to help you with such a vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json or yarn.lock files. Run npm install again and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It update by clearing the npm cache via sudo

npm install -g n

Install a new version of Node

n lts

n latest

Check id version is update

npm -v
8.19.3